How to enter insert mode in VIM with a Cyrillic layout
I'm using version 9.1 on Windows 11 and just started using Cyrillic in VIM.
None of the keys seem to take me from normal mode to insert.
Does anybody have a clue have one gets to insert mode, without having to switch the English (which can be done with a hotkey, but still)?

you might get better luck on [vi.se]
